# Remove text after element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove the text after the icon.

```
<i class="flagstrap-icon flagstrap-as" style="margin-right: 10px;">x</i>France

$('.flagstrap-icon').next().remove();
```

The problem is that next() will not work without an element.

Example `<span>France</span>`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8bn8e0q2/)

Any idea to remove the text after the icon?

Comment: Could you please post more complete html, what is the container of the `i` elements, how are they embeded

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I need to remove the text after the icon in this plugin, when a country is selected. http://blazeworx.github.io/flagstrap/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery can't really target nodes that aren't elements, but plain JS can

```
$('.flagstrap-icon').get(0).nextSibling.remove()
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8bn8e0q2/1/)

Note that this uses the native [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove), which is not supported in older browsers, if you have to support those, you'd do

```
var node = $('.flagstrap-icon').get(0).nextSibling;
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `<i>` element is in a parent container and there is no extra element in that container you can do something like:

```
$('.flagstrap-icon').parent().html($('<div>').append($('.flagstrap-icon').clone()).html());
```

However it won't work correctly if the parent contains other elements.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/v2tnh8t6/)

Comment: It doesn't work, just try in js console in the page of plugin.

Comment: @user455318, have a look at the demo. It shoulkd work, unless there are other problems like jQuery is not loaded at the point this code runs, or the text after `i` element is dynamically added after your code runs, ...