# JQuery selector for non wrapped text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I'm having trouble figuring out the JQuery selector for the following HTML. I'm trying to find the value that comes after "Type:" and before the final close div.

So far I'm trying:

```
$("div[itemscope] strong").children().text()
```

which is no where near.

HTML:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">
    <strong>
        <font size="" color="#404040">
            <span itemprop="name">The Yarmouth Inn</span>
        </font>
    </strong></a>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">&nbsp;&nbsp;30 West Street</span>, 
      <span itemprop="addressLocality">Yarmouth</span>, 
      <span itemprop="addressRegion">Kent</span>, 
      <span itemprop="postalCode">PQ10 4TG</span> 
    </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <strong>Type: </strong>Hotel
</div>
```

I want to access the word Hotel, just what ever the word Hotel is (depending on the type). Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you make a <p> or <h1> tag, put the text inside of it, give it an ID, then select it with JQuery?

Comment: I can't modify the HTML unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Get to the `nextSibling` of the last `<strong>` and take it's textContent

```js
var txt = $("div[itemscope] strong:last")[0].nextSibling.textContent

console.log('type is:', txt)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">
    <strong>
        <font size="" color="#404040">
            <span itemprop="name">The Yarmouth Inn</span>
        </font>
    </strong></a>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">&nbsp;&nbsp;30 West Street</span>, 
      <span itemprop="addressLocality">Yarmouth</span>, 
      <span itemprop="addressRegion">Kent</span>, 
      <span itemprop="postalCode">PQ10 4TG</span> 
    </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <strong>Type: </strong>Hotel
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `contents` to get all the children of the outer `div` and then filter based on the [`NodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType):

```js
console.log(
  $("div[itemscope]").has("a").contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).text()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">
    <strong>
        <font size="" color="#404040">
            <span itemprop="name">The Yarmouth Inn</span>
        </font>
    </strong></a>
  <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">&nbsp;&nbsp;30 West Street</span>,
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Yarmouth</span>,
    <span itemprop="addressRegion">Kent</span>,
    <span itemprop="postalCode">PQ10 4TG</span>
  </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>Type: </strong>Hotel
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have methods to access text that isn't in a specific element, but it can be done in plain Javascript. [Remove text after element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444322/remove-text-after-element) shows how to remove a text node like this, and similar code should work to return the content.

```js
console.log($("div[itemscope] > strong:last-child").get(0).nextSibling.textContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">
    <strong>
        <font size="" color="#404040">
            <span itemprop="name">The Yarmouth Inn</span>
        </font>
    </strong></a>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">&nbsp;&nbsp;30 West Street</span>, 
      <span itemprop="addressLocality">Yarmouth</span>, 
      <span itemprop="addressRegion">Kent</span>, 
      <span itemprop="postalCode">PQ10 4TG</span> 
    </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <strong>Type: </strong>Hotel
</div>
```